# VertexReplace destroys edge labels

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

```
g = 
  Graph[{2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> {2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> "hallo"}]
```

`g` has an edge pointing towards 3 from 2 labeled with `"hallo"`

```
g1 = VertexReplace[g, Thread[VertexList[g] -> ToString /@ VertexList[g]]];
```

`g1` doesn't have that edge label because the edge labels `2 -> 3 -> "hallo"` is still being identified using numerical $2$ and $3$.

Also I cannot save `g1` as a .png file: if I right click, I get this message:

> Set::write: Tag Inherited in Inherited[State] is Protected.

I am using Mathematica 11.0, My vertices are actually tuples like the following

```
g = 
  Graph[{{1,2} \[DirectedEdge] {2,3}}, 
    VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> {{1,2} \[DirectedEdge] {2,3} -> "hallo"}]
```

update with @m_goldberg's solution

```
In[15]:= Fold[
 SetProperty[{#1, #2}, VertexLabels -> ToString[#2]] &, g, 
 VertexList[g]]

During evaluation of In[15]:= SetProperty::pvobj: $Failed is not an object with properties.

Out[15]= SetProperty[{$Failed, {2, 3}}, VertexLabels -> "{2, 3}"]
```

Comment: Draw a graph to show what you want done.

Comment: The `Set::write:` message is a new but harmless bug in version 11.  I have already reported it, but it won't hurt if you report it too.

Comment: This message is blocking me from saving the graph as image.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use `SetProperty` and `Fold` for what you want to do.

```
g = 
  Graph[{2 \[DirectedEdge] 3},
    VertexLabels -> "Name",
    EdgeLabels -> {2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Style[" hello ", Background -> White]}]
```

[image: g]

```
Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, VertexLabels -> ToString[#2] <> "*"] &, g, VertexList[g]]
```

[image: xg]

Comment: Doesn't work if vertex identifiers are tuples, (question updated). However This is updating vertex label not vertex identifiers.