# How to add a list of vectors (lists) to a directed graph as an edge weight?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, vector

Why does following command not work in Mathematica 11.2?

```
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1},
      EdgeWeight -> {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

From the official docs about [EdgeWeight](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeWeight.html):

> The weight $w_i$ can be any expression.

Removing the weights everything looks ok:

[image]

### Update

The answer by @Carl Woll is good. If I want to display the EdgeWeights, there are also issues. Following does not work:

```
Block[{Identity}, 
      Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, 
       EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1} }, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]]
```

There is already a question discussing this:
[Label multiple edges between same vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72003/label-multiple-edges-between-same-vertices)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is worth reporting to support. A workaround is to use a wrapper to prevent [`EdgeWeight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeWeight) from interpreting a list as an edge specification:

```
Block[{Identity},
    Graph[
        {1\[DirectedEdge]1, 1\[DirectedEdge]1, 1\[DirectedEdge]1},
        EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{1,0},{0,1},{1,1}}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `VectorQ` is used to check the validity of the weight vector.  (It doesn't consider lists of lists to be vectors.)

Comment: @Carl Woll. Thanks for your solution. Could you have look at my edited question. Do you know how to solve my second issue as well?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I have question out of curiosity. If `VectorQ` is actually used (internally?), could be an easy solution to replace it by `ListQ`?

Comment: @Hotschke Please don't change the question to something different. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @Hotschke BTW this is a known limitation/bug of Mathematica: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92014/12  It can't handle properties in multigraphs.  There is very limited support for EdgeWeight/EdgeCapacty/EdgeCost, but no other properties will work, not even EdgeLabels.  I suggest you contact Wolfram Support about this. There are several post on this site describing how to work around the labelling/styling problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=edge+label+multigraph

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for your response and pointing out current limitations in Mathematica. My experience with Wolfram support is that it will take at least several months (or years) until Mathematica is fixed or extended. I can understand this for open-source projects but not for a software as expensive as Mathematica. I consider the support and the lack of completeness of existing functionality a weakness of Mathematica. They add constantly so many new features, but the already existing ones are not as flexible as one would expect.

Comment: @Szabolcs Regarding my change/extension of the question: I think using `{0,1}` or `a={1,0}` should make no difference. Using a vector-valued function felt close enough to the current question. But I can understand that you want to keep the scope of questions as narrow as possible. I will move it to a follow up question with reference to this one. I hope this is acceptable.

Comment: Also the referenced issue about limitation/bug of Mathematica from 2 1/2 years ago confirms my experience that I should not get my hopes up that  this will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: @Hotschke If no one asks for it to be fixed, it won't be fixed.  It has been suggested multiple times by WRI employees that the frequency of reporting may be considered when prioritizing a bug.

Comment: @Szabolcs. I certainly agree with you. However, I use right now a Home Edition of Mathematica with no subscription model. That means I have to pay for new releases. This makes it unattractive for me to report bugs because these kind of fixes will be added only to new versions not 11.2. And also the phrase '*may be considered when prioritizing a bug*' sounds very motivating writing a bug report. I actually have reported something else to Wolfram support: it got fixed two versions later. That doesn't sound too bad. But when you are working on something, it is.

Comment: @Hotschke You are not the only person affected by these problems.

Comment: @Carl Woll: When I right-click on the graphical output and want to `Save Graph As...`, I get only an error message: `Set::write: Tag Inherited in Inherited[State] is Protected.` The question [132009](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132009/13042) seems to be related. Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

> *If I want to display the EdgeWeights, there are also issues*.

Using Carl Woll's answer to generate a graph with edge weights and using a variant of the accepted answer in the linked q/a:

```
ClearAll[displayWeightedMultiGraph]
displayWeightedMultiGraph = Module[{i = 1, j, g = #, bcurves,
  labels = PropertyValue[#, EdgeWeight], 
  gccoords = Cases[ToBoxes[#], GraphicsComplexBox[x_, y_, z___] :> x, Infinity][[1]]}, 
  bcurves = Cases[ToBoxes[g], {dir___, ar : Longest[__ArrowBox], ___} :> 
    (## & @@ Thread[{dir, {ar}}]), Infinity] /. 
  {ArrowBox[BezierCurveBox[x_, y___], z___] :> 
     Arrow[BezierCurve[x /. k_Integer :> gccoords[[k]], y], z], 
   ArrowBox[x : {__}, y_] :> Arrow[gccoords[[x]], y]}; 
   SetProperty[g, EdgeShapeFunction -> ({j = i++; Text[labels[[j]], 
     BezierFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 7][0.5]], bcurves[[j]]} &)]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
g1 = Block[{Identity}, Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}, 
      EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1} }]];
displayWeightedMultiGraph @ g1
```

[image]

```
g2 = Block[{Identity}, Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 -> 2, 1 -> 2}, 
      EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]];
displayWeightedMultiGraph @ g2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This was certainly helpful as well. Unfortunately, I can only mark one as helpful to resolve my issues. You have +1 from me at least. Also I do not know whether a future version of Mathematica will change either the assignment or the display issue as well. Maybe the question itself becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Could you rewrite your code into a function `display_weighted_multigraph[g]` so it can be used on several occasions in a notebook?

Comment: And it does not work for `Block[{Identity}, 
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, 
  EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]` (containing an undirected edge with label `{0,0}`).

Comment: @Hotschke, Thank you for the vote. Carl's post answers your main question. Re the example in your last comment i will post an update if i can find a fix.

Comment: @Hotschke, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you! A small issue concerning the order is present: the undirected edge should have the label `{0,0}`. compare `EdgeList[g]` and `PropertyValue[g, EdgeWeight]`. I think the index should match.

Comment: In "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)", the code when copied into a fresh notebook and executed fails with the error "Symbol LineScaledCoordinate appears in multiple contexts".  However, the second time that the notebook is run, it works fine.  Moving `Needs["GraphUtilities\`"];` before the definition of `displayWeightedMultiGraph` solves this problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you. Made the change you suggested.

Comment: @Hotschke, good catch. I will update if I can find a fix.

Comment: @kglr Your last update introduced a problem: `BezierFunction[#, SplineDegree -> 7]` says `SplineDegree is not an option for BezierFunction`.

Comment: @kglr the old version has also a problem if I add vertex labels with `VertexLabels -> "Name"`

Comment: @kglr and hopefully finally: there are also problems with following larger graph `g = Block[{Identity}, Graph[ { 1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 6, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 6, 5 <-> 6, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 4, 5 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 6 \[DirectedEdge] 2 }, EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ { {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0} }]]`. I already try to decipher your code, but unfortunately my Mathematica knowledge is still quite limited and struggle to fit every piece of information together.

Comment: If you use `VertexLabels -> "Name"`, Mathematica does not use `GraphicsComplexBox` anymore. Try for yourself `ToBoxes[Block[{Identity}, 
  Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 1 -> 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]]]`. This means this answer as it stands does not work anymore.