# Why doesn't the low-level box representation of a graph with VertexLabels use GraphicsComplex?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, implementation-details, boxes

Compare following two [low-level box representations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookStructure.html) of a graph without `VertexLabels` and one with `VertexLabels` set to `"Name"` with [`ToBoxes[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToBoxes.html):

```
ToBoxes[Graph[{1 <-> 2}]]

ToBoxes[Graph[{1 <-> 2}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

(Alternatively, select visual representation and press `Cmd+Shift+E` on mac.)

The first one uses [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html) for an efficient representation of the graph and the second does not.

[image]

Is there a conceptual or technical reason for this?

I came across this trying to use [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169265/13042) for a graph with `VertexLabels` enabled where `GraphicsComplexBox[x_, y_, z___]` does not match anything anymore.

Mathematica version: 11.2

Comment: Well, I made the experience that everything involving `PropertyValues`  for `Graphs` is handled quite differently than without (and often in an inconsistent way but that's another story). This is maybe because there can be so many exceptions... And using `VertexLabels` also implies that your graph is not overly large so that the profit from `GraphicsComplex` is marginal, right? Maybe that was the thinking behind this design decision...

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I guess you are right that you only place labels when you have a graph not with thousands of vertices. Do you know if there is a way to use  [`Normal[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) or another function to get an identical representation for both?

Comment: Hm. `AdjacencyGraph@AdjacencyMatrix` should get rid of all `PropertyValues`. Plotting it leads to a `GraphicsComplex`, but the vertex lables, vertex coordinates, etc. are gone. Is that what you need?

Comment: You can also use `H = Graph[VertexList[G], EdgeList[G]]`. Depending on the internal representation of the graph (sparse or not), the one or the other may be faster.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear. I meant the same low-level box representation. I did not mean to strip of all PropertyValues. I want to adjust the function `displayWeightedMultiGraph` shown in the [mentioned answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169265/13042)  to handle both situations.

Comment: Okay, is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)? What is it what you _really_ want? Have you also seen [Carl's great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167670/38178)? Look, this works: `Block[{Identity}, 
 Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 1},
  EdgeWeight -> Identity /@ {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}},
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"
  ]
 ]`.

Comment: Sorry that the other issue contains actually two problems. One is solved by Carl (and has therefore the green mark) and is used in the answer by kglr answering the problem of visualization. So no, it is not an xy problem.  I have already tried to ask kglr to help me out, but he didn't respond so I try it myself in steps. Writing a complex rule for a graph using GraphicsComplex and one without is not what I would ideally want to do .

Comment: Once again: Why do you want to write "a complex rule for a graph using GraphicsComplex"? Have you noticed the use of `EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"`, which resolves the display issue?

Comment: I guess you are not aware of the problems of mixed (directed and undirected edges) multi-graphs pointed out by [Szabolc](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167668/how-to-add-a-list-of-vectors-lists-to-a-directed-graph-as-an-edge-weight/169265#comment442728_167670). I try to resolve it manually. But it is very hard to do. I am little bit disappointed with Mathematica. Also `Normal[Graph]` does not work. The documentation sounds promising but again does not work here because the undocumented `GraphicsComplexBox` is used.

Comment: Thanks for your interest! But I feel like we cannot resolve it together. At least not today :). Do not invest too much time in this!