# A Bug about VertexWeight in Mathematica 11.0.1

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The document of the command **VertexWeight** claimed that:
[image]

However, I found that it throw wrong result when I use a list as member of VertexWeight, as can be seen below:
[image]

Comment: closely related [How to add a list of vectors (lists) to a directed graph as an edge weight?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167668/125)

Comment: The trick in Carl's answer in the linked q/a also works here: `g=Block[{Identity}, 
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <->   3,  3 <->   1}, 
  VertexWeight -> Identity /@ {RandomImage[1,{5,5}, ImageSize->40], RandomImage[1,{5,5}, ImageSize->50, ColorSpace->"RGB"] , {1, 1}}]]`

Comment: If you find a bug, *please report it to Wolfram directly*.  That's the only way to get them to fix it.  Have you done it already?

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution you mentioned above is a good choice, but not perfect. If I use g=Block[...], I can not change the property of g, for example, PropertyValue[{g, 3}, VertexWeight] = {2, 4}. So, I took a compromise solution: g=Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, VertexWeight ->{ PE[x1,y1] , PE[x2,y2] ,  PE[x3,y3] }. When I need use these values of VertexWeight to compute, I can use rule (->) to do everything as usual, and I can also change it.